# htaccess rewrite and preserve slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite all URL's to `test.php` on my website, to point to `index.php?page=test` instead (where "test" can be replaced with any other word). This seems to work correctly.

However, I would also like to rewrite all requests to `test/testpage.php` to point to `index.php?page=test/testpage` instead. But with my current .htaccess, this does not seem to work. I get a 404 error instead.

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/?]*)\.php$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tweak your regex pattern:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`.+` will match any character 1 or more times.